# How do I protect a page only for logged users?

Tags: php

I created a login form that works great.  But I realized the page my user is directed to can still be accessed by anybody.  How do I protect the page being accessed only viewable by those logged in?

Do I need to place a script on the success page itself?

Here is my check_login.php:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="xxx"; // Mysql username
$password="xxx"; // Mysql password
$db_name="xxx"; // Database name
$tbl_name="xxx"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

$user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

 if( isset($user_info['url']) ) {

 session_register("myusername");
 session_register("mypassword");
     header('Location: ' . $user_info['url']); //Redirects to the supplied url from the DB
 } else {
  header("location:error.htm");
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but you will want to fix your query or you may have a sql injection attack that compromises your database.  Also, get in the habit of `exit`ing from the script when you send a Location header.

Comment: @sberry2A: I don't see much problem with the SQL but +1 for the `exit` advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every of your page should start with

```
session_start();
```

and you should not be using `session_register( "variablename" )` as of PHP version 4.2, use

```
$_SESSION["variable"] = value;
```

so example page with is-logged-it checking would be:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["loggedIn"] != true) {
    echo("Access denied!");
    exit();
}
echo("Enter my lord!");
?>
```

and logging-in script:

```
<?php
    /*
        ... db stuff ...
    */

if( isset($user_info['url']) ) {
    $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
    $_SESSION["username"] = $myusername;
    header('Location: ' . $user_info['url']); //Redirects to the supplied url from the DB
} else {
    header("Location: error.htm");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

On the page that requires the user to be logged in check to see if they have a valid session. If not send them to the login page.

```
if (!$_SESSION['myusername'])  
{  
    header('location: /login.php');  
    exit;  
}
```

Comment: Do I wrap this in a javascript tag on the top of the page?

Comment: that is php. and yes would be at top of the page after   session_start(); is called

Answer (score 2):

In each page/content with restricted access, you should authenticate the client/user. If people were crazy then you'd have to make the user fill in his details (username/password) in every page, but thanks to "HTTP cookies" - we don't have to do that.

Comment: So I need to place a script in the page that authenticates, yes?  What would a script look like?  Is it javascript or php?

Comment: Yes. It should be PHP (JS is useless, since it's a client-side code)

Comment: Is there example I could see?

Comment: The webpage linked by @Dor is very old. for example `get_magic_quotes_gpc` was removed from PHP 5.4

Answer (score 1):

You should basically use session management to track whether a user is in an authenticated session or not. If not, you (re)direct them to the index page; if yes, you grant them access to whichever resource they requested.

To use sessions, put your session setup functions at the top *of every PHP script* inside your application (setup functions include session handler, cookie domain and cookie name), and say `session_start()`. Then, check if a login flag has been defined in the current session like `$_SESSION["user_is_logged_in"]`. In the authentication page, you would of course define `$_SESSION["user_is_logged_in"] = true;` at some stage.

Answer (score -1):

It is recommended to outsource the access data to the database.
I saved it as "config.php":

```
<?php
      /* include of the access data */
require_once("yourPath/config.php");

      /* Connection establishment */
try {
    $mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $passwort);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "SQL Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```