# LinkedIn Login as Authentication for PHP pages

Tags: php, session, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have built a website which I would like users to be able to only login with LinkedIn accounts. I managed the LinkedIn connection using this tutorial: http://thinkdiff.net/linkedin/integrate-linkedin-api-in-your-site/ however I am a bit stuck because I would like my php pages (home.php, account.php, etc..) to only be accessible if you are logged in via LinkedIn. So far I can login using LinkedIn (like the tutorial) but I can also access pages, which are supposed to be authorized using LinkedIn, directly from their URL.

I believe in order to accomplish this I have to store some authentication response from LinkedIn value in a session variable and then checking on each .php page, that is to be secured, to see if that value is set.

Any help would be great, as all the SO posts I have read regarding LinkedIn have hyperlinks to no longer existing API & code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to store the login in the session variable and then put some PHP at the front of every page that you want to protect. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810312/721263) has the code you need.