# session in login framework

Tags: php, session, frameworks

For school I am making a login system. Now the next step is that when the user is logged in the button 'log out' wil appear on every page. I know i have to do it with the $_SESSION but i don't know how to use it in my code. I hope someone can help me out?!

loginModel:

```
function loginUser($username = null, $password = null){
$username = $_POST["username"]; 
$password = $_POST["password"]; 

$db = openDatabaseConnection();

$result1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username' AND  password = '$password'");
$result1->execute();
if($result1->rowCount() > 0 )
{
    $_SESSION['logged in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $db = null;
    return true;
}

else
{
    $db = null;
    return false;
}
```

}

loginController:

```
function login(){
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    if(loginUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        header("Location:" . URL . "login/index");
    }else{
            render("login/login");
        echo 'ownee het is een fout help';
    }
}
else
{
    render("login/login");
}
}
```

Comment: basically, after the user logged in, you grant access to any page that should start with <?php session_start(); /* before any output */ then you check for the status with $_SESSION['logged in'] value. if ok, then do whatever you need. IMPORTANT : you shall read about [THIS](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.password-hash.php) and [THIS](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: can you just show me that in a example?

Comment: what is 'that' ? you mean a prepared statement with password_verify ? or a protected page ? as well as [your best friend](https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=php+mysqli+prepared+statement+login), SO Q/A can help [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452614/php-mysqli-prepared-staments-login-and-check-the-user-status) or [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810221/how-do-i-protect-a-page-only-for-logged-users). But please don't try to just copy the code, read and understand it :) NOTE: beware of the outdated and unsafe 'md5' used in a script that I linked to !